# Is it possible to define a spatial resolution for a Geometry column in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, resolution, data-management

In various spatial file formats, it is possible to define the spatial resolution (tolerance), for which a vector geometry is saved and treated ([Oracle DB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/spatial-concepts.html#GUID-3C14F80F-10BF-48B3-BED8-FECBBF26D233), [ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/the-properties-of-a-spatial-reference.htm#GUID-FFE1E21B-A459-4AC7-A8C5-222C0341A9AE)). e.g. if the geometry layer is using a meter based SRID\CRS, and the spatial resolution is 0.001 for all the geometry's dimensions, then each vertex' dimension will be saved\treated in a 1 mm resolution.

Is this configuration supported using PostGIS' [Geometry data type](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geometry)? If so, how can one do it? If not, what is the resolution used?

Comment: [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) looks like your candidate

Comment: Thank you @Vince for the suggestion. I think that your suggestion can be applied in an INSERT and UPDATE trigger, for which every Geometry row will be enforced to a certain grid resolution. Yet, my question initial aim was more from the data structure and storage side of things: e.g.: can the a Geometry be stored in less space?; does spatial functions use the resolution parameter? Therefore, I think a full answer should look more like "There's no official support for changing spatial resolution in PostGIS. It is set as FLOAT data type. Yet, a workaround can be made...".  Again, thank you:)

Comment: Self-answering is encouraged here. That seems like it would be a fine answer.

Comment: PostGIS is always using GEOS that has a precision model https://libgeos.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1PrecisionModel.html#details that inherits from JTS https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/PrecisionModel.html. It may be possible to handle tolerances also in some other way than with ST_SnapToGrid that is the best known method. See also this 10 years old wiki page https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/ToleranceDiscussion.

Comment: PostGIS coordinates are stored as doubles but when it comes to storage size read this https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things when talking about geometry precision: disk space required to save the geometry and the precision used when comparing two geometries against each other.

**About the disk usage:**
PostGIS saves all coordinates as double precision floats internally. There are no options to change this. But PostgreSQL tries to optimize its disk usage by compressing fields. There is a function [ST_QuantizeCoordinates](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html) that sets insignificant bits of the double precision float so that the geometry is compressible as possible. Backgrounds of this function can be read from [a blog post](http://www.danbaston.com/posts/2018/02/15/optimizing-postgis-geometries.html).

ST_SnapToGrid or ST_ReducePrecision doesn't affect the space required on disk if those don't remove duplicate points from the geometry.

```sql
-- 50% disk space saving can be achieved if 0.001m precision is enough:

create table size_test as
select 
  st_setsrid(
    ST_Buffer(
      ST_Makepoint(
        240000 + 50000*random(),
        6720000 + 50000*random()
      ), 
      500*random(),
      128
    ),
    3067
  )::geometry(polygon, 3067) AS geom
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);
;
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"size_test"'));
-- 782 MB


CREATE TABLE size_test_3digit_precision AS SELECT ST_QuantizeCoordinates(geom, 3) FROM size_test;
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"size_test_3digit_precision"'));
-- 393 MB
```

**About the precision in geometry operations:**
Since PostGIS doesn't fully support precision model comparing and calculating with float coordinates can lead to weird results e.g. the intersection point of two intersecting lines does not intersect with lines:

```sql
WITH
g1 as (
  select 'SRID=3067;LINESTRING(332970.063 6881856.813, 527822.563 7052718.563)'::geometry as geom
),
g2 as (
  select 'SRID=3067;LINESTRING(332970.063 7052718.563, 520800.813 6859621.313)'::geometry as geom
)
select
  st_intersects(st_intersection(g1.geom, g2.geom), g1.geom)
from g1, g2;
-- false
```

I think testing intersection between points and lines must be currently done with st_dwithin:

```sql
select ST_DWithin(st_intersection(g1.geom, g2.geom), g1.geom, 0.001)
-- true
```

In other kind of comparisons it might help to run the geometries through the ST_SnapToGrid first to get consistent resolution.

I said that PostGIS doesn't fully support precision model. In PostGIS 3.1 with GEOS 3.9 [few functions got support](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3.1-geos-3.9) for fixed precision model. ST_Intersection, ST_Union and ST_Difference support now gridSize parameter which gives some help to the situation.